Custom LoRa SX1276 schematic design considerations for 868MHz
I have a few questions on designing a custom PCB for the szx1276 for my application using the ESP32S3 MCU. I am using the reference design [SX1276RF1IAS - 169/868 MHz with TCXO] from Semtech website.

I do not want to use the 169Mhz band. I will be using the 868Mhz band for communication. So can I discard the circuitry for the 169Mhz on pins RFI_LF and PA_BOOST.

What are the specifications for the SAW filter IC [U4] on the RFI_HF pin? The BOM shows U4 as a 0R resistor.

What is the FEM_CTX mentioned at the CTRL pin of the RF switch HF as RXTX_RF controls the incoming and outgoing communication?



